# how do i suppress model training(gbm method) summary image?

Tags: r, gbm

Here's my code:

```
rgb <- gbm(target ~ . , data = gb_train, distribution = 'bernoulli',
                   interaction.depth = 4, n.trees = 1000, cv.folds = 12)
```

data is a data frame containing 10 columns and one of which is the target column (categorical)
I'm trying to use the data frame that `'summary(rgb)$rel.inf'` gives, but it also prints out an image of the ranking order, how do i suppress this image from popping out in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`summary.gbm` has an argument `plotit` you can modify:

```
summary(rgb, plotit = FALSE)$rel.inf
```